# Tidy not closing <hr> tag

Tags: php, html, tidy

I'm trying to use the tidy functions to clean up an html string that doesn't have a closing `</hr>` tag:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I use the following lines:

```
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($data);
tidy_clean_repair($tidy);
echo ($tidy);
```

the `</hr>` tag isn't being added, outputting:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor='white'>
<center>
<h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1>
</center>
<hr>
<center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Is the tidy library just not capable of closing an `<hr>` tag or am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean you want `<hr>` to have `</hr>`, its a void element, it doesn't need to be closed

Comment: Well when I try make a SimpleXMLElement out of the unclosed string, I get an error, but when its closed there are no errors. Thats why I need it closed.

Comment: then use the less strict `DOMDocument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `<hr>` (thematic break) tag is not one to be closed.

From [W3C -> hr](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hr.html):

> The hr element is a void element. An hr element must have a start tag but **must not have an end tag**.

---

If you really have to, you could do this:

```
$html = str_replace('<hr>', '<hr/>', $html);
```

That will *pretend* the tag is *self-closing* and prevent `SimpleXMLElement` from going hysterical about not closing it.

Comment: I'm trying to make a SimpleXMLElement out of the string so thats why I need it closed. When its closed I get no errors but when its open I can't do it.

Comment: Yea I might have to end up doing that. I'm new to PHP so I'm trying to figure out how I can make a function that just inserts a closing </hr> tag right before the </html> tag.

Comment: Ah. Yea that seems to work with making a SimpleXMLElement. Thanks.